# Insert data from form into MYSQL using Node JS

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying inserting the data into MySQL using node and Express framework from a HTML form. The code for the form is :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Personal Information</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="info">
<h1>Personal Information</h1>
<form action="/myaction" method="post">

        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" />
    <br><br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    <br><br>
        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Enter your city" />
    <br><br>
    <label for="pincode">Pincode:</label>
        <input type="text" id="pincode" name="pincode" placeholder="Enter your pincode" />
    <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the .js file is :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ejs = require('ejs');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 3000
var MYSQL_USER = 'root';
var MYSQL_PASS = 'jelly123#';
var DATABASE = 'form';
var TABLE = 'info'; 

var mysql = mysql.createConnection({
host: HOST,
port: PORT,
user: MYSQL_USER,
password: MYSQL_PASS,
});
app.get('/home',function(req,res,next){
res.sendfile('views/forms.html');
});
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
console.log('req.body');
console.log(req.body);
res.write('You sent the name "' + req.body.name+'".\n');
res.write('You sent the Email "' + req.body.email+'".\n');
res.write('You sent the City "' + req.body.city+'".\n');
res.write('You sent the Pincode "' + req.body.pincode+'".\n');
res.end()

mysql.query("Insert into "+TABLE+" (name,email,city,pincode) VALUES ('"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.email+"','"+req.body.city+"','"+req.body.pincode+"')",function(err, result)      
{                                                      
  if (err)
     throw err;
});
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Example app listening at port:3000');
```

I am able to enter the form data and display it in the page http://localhost:3000/myaction but unable to Insert data into database Please mention where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ejs = require('ejs');
var pg = require('pg');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 


        var conString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || "postgres://postgres:Emdsystems@localhost:5432/student";
        var client = new pg.Client(conString);
        client.connect();

app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
res.sendfile('views/forms.html');
});

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {

console.log('req.body');
console.log(req.body);
res.write('You sent the name "' + req.body.name+'".\n');
res.write('You sent the Email "' + req.body.email+'".\n');
res.write('You sent the City "' + req.body.city+'".\n');
res.write('You sent the Pincode "' + req.body.pincode+'".\n');
res.end()

client.query("Insert into record (name,email,city,pincode) VALUES ('"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.email+"','"+req.body.city+"','"+req.body.pincode+"')",function(err, result)      
{                                                      
  if (err)
     throw err;
});
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Example app listening at port:3000');
```

Comment: come on man!!! he asked about saving in MySQL db but you're giving solutions of postgres `pg = require('pg')`!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mysql.query('select id, name, price from ' + TABLE + ' where price < 100',
function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
        console.log('Gadgets which costs less than $100');
        console.log('----------------------------------');
        for (var i in result) {
            var gadget = result[i];
            console.log(gadget.name +': '+ gadget.price);
        }
    }
});
```

reference: http://www.hacksparrow.com/using-mysql-with-node-js.html

Answer (score 1):

This my js file-

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "mydb"
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});
app.post('/submit',function(req,res){

  var name=req.body.name;
  var email=req.body.email;
  var username=req.body.username;
  res.write('You sent the name "' + req.body.name+'".\n');
  res.write('You sent the email "' + req.body.email+'".\n');
  res.write('You sent the username "' + req.body.username+'".\n');

  con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var sql = "INSERT INTO form (name, email,description) VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+email+"','"+username+"')";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
     res.end();
  });
  });
})
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

---

This my html file-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> test </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="/submit" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" autofocus />
                <br/>
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  />
                <br/>
                <label for="username">User name: </label>
                <input type="textbox" id="username" name="username" />
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="create profile" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

i am doing this with express js in node
pre-requisites:install node js,mysql,express,express-generator

Write this in index.jade file

```
<html>
<head>
<title> test </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="/submitform/" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" autofocus />
<br/>
<label for="email">Email: </label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email"  />
<br/>
<label for="description">Description: </label>
<textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="create profile" />
</fieldset>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Than ,write this in index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
     host: "localhost",
     user: "root",
     password: "",
     database: "testn"
});

router.post('/submitform', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.name);
    console.log(req.body.email);
    console.log(req.body.description);
    con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw  err;
  console.log("connected");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO `form`(`name`,`email`, `description`) VALUES ('"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.email+"','"+req.body.description+"')";
  con.query(sql, function(err, result)  {
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log("table created");
  });
});

  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

This code will insert values from form into MySql in node js

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
    index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Registration Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    .error{
        color: red;
        font-style: italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type='text' class="btn btn-primary" id="showbtn">Show/Hide Form</button>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class = "panel panel-primary">
                <div class = "panel-heading">
                    Registration
                </div>
                <div class = "panel-body">
                    <form id = "registration" action="http://127.0.0.1:7744/register">
                        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "username" placeholder = "Username"/>
                        <br/>
                        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "email" placeholder = "Email"/>
                        <br/>
                        <input type = "password" class = "form-control" name = "password" placeholder = "Password" id = "password"/>
                        <br/>
                        <input type = "password" class = "form-control" name = "confirm" placeholder = "Confirm Password"/>
                        <br/>
                        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "fname" placeholder = "First Name"/>
                        <br/>
                        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "lname" placeholder = "Last Name"/>
                        <br/>
                        <div class = "gender">
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" class = "form-contorl"/>Male</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" class = "form-contorl"/>Female</label>       
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <select class = "form-control" name = "city">
                            <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">--SELECT--</option>
                            <option>Delhi</option>
                            <option>Ghaziabad</option>
                            <option>Noida</option>
                            <option>Faridabad</option>
                            <option>GuruGram</option>
                        </select>
                        <br/>
                        <textarea class = "form-control" name = "address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                        <br/>
                        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script> $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function (value, element) {
            return value == '' || value.trim().length != 0;
        }, "No space please and don't leave it empty");
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("customEmail", function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(value);
        }, "Please enter valid email address!");
        $.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/i.test(value);
        }, "Letters, numbers, and underscores only please");
        var $registrationForm = $('#registration');
        if ($registrationForm.length) {
            $registrationForm.validate({
                rules: {
                    username: {
                        required: true,
                        alphanumeric: true
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        customEmail: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    confirm: {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: '#password'
                    },
                    fname: {
                        required: true,
                        noSpace: true
                    },
                    lname: {
                        required: true,
                        noSpace: true
                    },
                    gender: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    country: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    address: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    username: {
                        required: 'Please enter username!'
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: 'Please enter email!',
                        email: 'Please enter valid email!'
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: 'Please enter password!'
                    },
                    confirm: {
                        required: 'Please enter confirm password!',
                        equalTo: 'Please enter same password!'
                    },
                    fname: {
                        required: 'Please enter first name!'
                    },
                    lname: {
                        required: 'Please enter last name!'
                    },
                    country: {
                        required: 'Please select country!'
                    },
                    address: {
                        required: 'Please enter address!'
                    }
                },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    if (element.is(":radio")) {
                        error.appendTo(element.parents('.gender'));
                    }
                    else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
    
                }
            });
        }else{
            alert("submitted");
        }
    
        $('#showbtn').click(function () {
            $('.container').fadeToggle('slow');
        });
    
    });
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

index.js Server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'node_form'
});
connection.connect();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
})


app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
    var fname = req.query.fname;
            var lname = req.query.lname;
            var username = req.query.username;
            var gender = req.query.gender;
            var email = req.query.email;
            var city = req.query.city;
            var password = req.query.password;
            var address = req.query.address;
            var confirm = req.query.confirm;

    var check = "select * from registration where email = '" + email + "' or username = '" + username + "'";
    connection.query(check, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else if (result.length !== 0) {
            console.log("user already exist");
        }
        else {
            
            var user = {
                fname: fname,
                lname:lname,
                username:username,
                gender:gender,
                email:email,
                city:city,
                password:password,
                address:address
            };

            if (password !== confirm) {
                console.log("password and confirm password not match")
            } else {
                connection.query('insert into registration set ?', user, function (err, rs) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Form submitted successfully');
                    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
                })
            }
        }
    })
})

var server = app.listen(7744, function () {
    console.log("server started");
})
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you explain your solution as well. It will help people to better understand it